# Exchange Online: New-DkimSigningConfig cmdlet not found with some Tenants

Tags: azure, powershell-cmdlet, azure-appservice, dkim, exchange-online

We use powerscript with EXO on many tenants where we have created an App in the Azure portal. This app has Office 365 Exchange Online application permissions:

- full_access_as_app
- Exchange.ManageAsApp

Also we assigned the App the Exchange Administrator role. On allmost all tenants the following works:

We can with  `Connect-ExchangeOnline -UserPrincipalName "administrator@somedomain.com" -AccessToken "SomeToken"`

Then we use `New-DkimSigningConfig` and `Set-DkimSigningConfig` so make adjustments around the DKIM signing config.

Yet with just a handful of tenants the cmdlet is not available, it gives the following error:

```
New-DkimSigningConfig : The term 'New-DkimSigningConfig' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

Set-DkimSigningConfig : The term 'Set-DkimSigningConfig' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct 
and try again.
```

The weird thing is that `Get-DkimSigningConfig` works, this cmdlet is available.

We are using the following installed module: `ExchangeOnlineManagement 3.2.0`

I tried to delete the App in the Azure portal, recreate it, assign the new one to the Exchange Administrator role... yet nothing changed.

So I guess something is different with those tenants or this is a bug... Am I missing something?

Comment: If you can run the Get-* cmdlet, but not the 'Set-*' or 'New-*' cmdlets, I'd suspect an issue with permissions. It could be related to PIM enabled roles, which need to be activated before use and remain active for a period of time. Not sure if applicable in your case.

Comment: Well I deleted the app, created a new one, set all permissions, nothing changed... Next day I tried and I was able to use the set / new cmdlet... So I still have no clue what is going wrong here...